# tSQL: Return every table containing a specfic key value

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, key-value

The title pretty much says it all.

I have a large database & am trying to troubleshoot some issues.

I want to compare the state of a 'good' record in the db with the state of a 'bad' record.

The most comprehensive way I could think to do this was to compare the rows of each record in every table where a key value for them exists.

Just a query that tells me every table that contains each records key value would be spectacular.

Thank you in advance for your help!

PS This is what I have right now.

select name 
from sys.tables 
where exists (select <*key-value*> from *table* where <*key-value*> = '*string*')

It seems to work, but if someone wouldn't mind ensuring that it is indeed returning what I am expecting that would be great too.

Comment: So you want to find all the tables which have a column named MyColumn with a value of 'myValue'?

Comment: Correct, Tony. All tables that have the Key-value column and contain a specific set of key values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay here's a start using cursors, exec, and print. Note not checked might be a typo especially building sql to check for values in the table.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @table_name VarChar(255)
Declare @column_name VarChar(255)
Declare @column_value VarChar(255)

Select @column_name = 'MyColumnName'
Select @column_value = 'MyColumnValue'

DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns 
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name = @column_name

OPEN table_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @table_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  Exec('If Exists(Select 1 From ' + @table_name + 'Where ' + @column_name + '=''' + @column_value + ''' Print ' + @table_name)
  FETCH NEXT FROM vendor_cursor INTO @table_name, @vendor_name
END 
CLOSE table_cursor
DEALLOCATE table_cursor
```

Cursors and dynamic sql are a useful technique for this sort of thing, but for Cthulhu's sake don't do anything like this in application code...

Comment: I'm getting the error: The name "<TableNameIsHereInDoubleQoutes>" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Comment: Copy, paste and edit failure, never happened before. :)

Answer (score 1):

@TonyHopkinson 
I had to add the 'c' alias for sys.columns and wrap the last variable in the dynamic query with single quotes.
Also, replaced vendor_cursor with table_cursor and removed the variable @vendor_name

After these edits it worked like a charm! Thanks, Tony!!

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

Declare @table_name VarChar(255)
Declare @column_name VarChar(255)
Declare @column_value VarChar(255)

Select @column_name = 'MyColumnNam' 
Select @column_value = 'MyColumnVal'

DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT t.name 
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name = @column_name 

OPEN table_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @table_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  Exec('If exists(Select 1 From ' + @table_name + ' t Where t.' + @column_name + '='''+ @column_value+ ''') Print '''+ @table_name+'''')
  FETCH NEXT FROM table_cursor INTO @table_name
END 
CLOSE table_cursor
DEALLOCATE table_cursor
```